# How to change status of Seller Fullfilled Orders that are Confirmed Shipped to Delivered

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

Although the package and order was delivered by a **non Amazon carrier** ( not USPS, UPS.. ) , the buyer is not seeing the order in delivered status.  It is showing *Running late* in the buyers account.

I tried to look up various other SP-API operations to check if seller/shipper can set the shipment tracking status to Delivered but could not find any.

For example - Feeds API Order Fulfillment Feed also does not seem useful.  Also POST /vendor/directFulfillment/shipping/v1/shipmentStatusUpdates seems to be for Vendor Shipments and not Seller Shipments. https://spapi.cyou/zh/references/vendorDirectFulfillmentShippingV1.html#%E6%8F%90%E4%BA%A4%E5%8F%91%E8%B4%A7%E7%A1%AE%E8%AE%A4

The seller/shipper used operation *updateShipmentStatus* SP-API to confirm shipment of order and is showing Shipped since 10 days in seller central. The carrier was a non amazon carrier and and tracking id was updated without a URL of the carrier.
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference#updateshipmentstatusrequest

For operation *updateShipmentStatus* the enumeration of the field Shipment Status also just contains ReadyforPickup, Pickedup or RefusedPickup https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference#shipmentstatus and does not allow us to update shipment to delivered.

Although the item is delivered,  we do not want the customer/consignee to be able to *request for refund* just because they keep seeing this order as **late** on Amazon.

We want a way to logically complete the process and mark the order as **Delivered** using SP-API.

On a separate note - For another order the shipper has also tried to send the full URL of the carrier tracking site in the tracking number field. However it is observed that the order shipped email notification was not sent by Amazon in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the `POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA` feed type to update the shipment tracking information and delivery status which successfully updates Amazon orders with the tracking and status of the shipment.

Here is an example of how the feed needs to look:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Header>
                <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
                <MerchantIdentifier>XXX</MerchantIdentifier>
            </Header>
            <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
            <Message>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <OrderFulfillment>
                    <AmazonOrderID>XXX</AmazonOrderID>
                    <FulfillmentDate>2022-07-05T14:48:00.000Z</FulfillmentDate>
                    <FulfillmentData>
                        <CarrierCode>USPS</CarrierCode>
                        <ShippingMethod>Standard</ShippingMethod>
                        <ShipperTrackingNumber>XXX</ShipperTrackingNumber>
                    </FulfillmentData>
                </OrderFulfillment>
            </Message>
        </AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: Amazon pulls status of the delivery from USPS, UPS and other integrated carriers from their respective sites.  This is exactly what we want to happen when we are using a *non Amazon carrier*.  Do you have suggestions how to update the tracking update for a carrier that is not in the list. I did not see a place to pass the tracking URL or configure the carrier tracking site on seller central. Thanks for your feedback here.